# Is "give a party" regional?

Tags: dialects

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31986) on the ELL SE says that "give a party" is interchangeable with "throw/hold a party:"

> > What is the difference between "hold a party", "have a party", "give a party" and "throw a party"?
>
> I think they're all pretty much interchangeable.

Everyone on [this forum thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/give-a-party-vs-throw-a-party.2528204/) takes the phrase in stride:

> You might give a formal tea party, but you would not throw a formal tea party - even if you were discussing it informally.

I haven't heard "give a party" used before. Is it regional (or have I just missed it somehow)? If so, where's it most used? (I'm in Colorado)

Comment: I'm from the midwest US, and it's a familiar usage to me.  I'd say that "give" is the most common, though people wouldn't bat an eye at "hold", "have", or "throw".

Comment: In Scotland there’s also [getting a party](https://www.scotsman.com/200voices/kevin-bridges-top-jokes/).

Comment: Throw a party is far more casual than give a party. Polite society gives parties; wilder groups throw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A century ago, your friends would nearly always ***give*** a party, as [this NGram shows...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friends%20had%20a%20party%2Cfriends%20gave%20a%20party&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriends%20had%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriends%20gave%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

(If you change the corpus to BrE in that link, you'll see we haven't changed much cisatlantic!)

---

I don't know about regional variance, but [overall AmE preferences](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friends%20had%20a%20party%2Cfriends%20gave%20a%20party%2Cfriends%20held%20a%20party%2Cfriends%20threw%20a%20party&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriends%20had%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriends%20gave%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriends%20held%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriends%20threw%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0) for the past century are...

[image]

And personally I'd be quite happy if my friends ***staged / hosted / organised*** a party for me!